# Performance decrease with threaded implementation

Tags: linux, windows, performance, pthreads

I implemented a small program in C to calculate PI using a Monte Carlo method (mainly because of personal interest and training). After having implemented the basic code structure, I added a command-line option allowing to execute the calculations threaded.

I expected major speed ups, but I got disappointed. The command-line synopsis should be clear. The final number of iterations made to approximate PI is the product of the number of `-iterations` and `-threads` passed via the command-line. Leaving `-threads` blank defaults it to `1` thread resulting in execution in the main thread.

The tests below are tested with 80 Million iterations in total.

#### On Windows 7 64Bit (Intel Core2Duo Machine):

[image: Windows Stats]

Compiled using Cygwin GCC 4.5.3: `gcc-4 pi.c -o pi.exe -O3`

#### On Ubuntu/Linaro 12.04 (8Core AMD):

[image: Linux Stats]

Compiled using GCC 4.6.3: `gcc pi.c -lm -lpthread -O3 -o pi`

### Performance

On Windows, the threaded version is a few milliseconds faster than the un-threaded. I expected a better performance, to be honest. On Linux, ew! What the heck? Why does it take even 2000% longer? Of course this is depending much on the implementation, so here it goes. An excerpt after the command-line argument parsing was done and the calculation is started:

```
    // Begin computation.
    clock_t t_start, t_delta;
    double pi = 0;

    if (args.threads == 1) {
        t_start = clock();
        pi = pi_mc(args.iterations);
        t_delta = clock() - t_start;
    }
    else {
        pthread_t* threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * args.threads);
        if (!threads) {
            return alloc_failed();
        }

        struct PIThreadData* values = malloc(sizeof(struct PIThreadData) * args.threads);
        if (!values) {
            free(threads);
            return alloc_failed();
        }

        t_start = clock();
        for (i=0; i < args.threads; i++) {
            values[i].iterations = args.iterations;
            values[i].out = 0.0;
            pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, pi_mc_threaded, values + i);
        }
        for (i=0; i < args.threads; i++) {
            pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
            pi += values[i].out;
        }
        t_delta = clock() - t_start;

        free(threads);
        threads = NULL;
        free(values);
        values = NULL;

        pi /= (double) args.threads;
    }
```

While `pi_mc_threaded()` is implemented as:

```
struct PIThreadData {
    int iterations;
    double out;
};

void* pi_mc_threaded(void* ptr) {
    struct PIThreadData* data = ptr;
    data->out = pi_mc(data->iterations);
}
```

You can find the full source code at http://pastebin.com/jptBTgwr.

### Question

Why is this? Why this extreme difference on Linux? I expected the anmount of time taken to calculate to be at least 3/4 of the original time. It would of course be possible that I simply made wrong use of the `pthread` library. A clarifcation on how to do correct in this case would be very nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that in glibc's implementation, `rand()` calls [`__random()`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;hb=glibc-2.15#l292), and that

```
long int
__random ()
{
  int32_t retval;

  __libc_lock_lock (lock);

  (void) __random_r (&unsafe_state, &retval);

  __libc_lock_unlock (lock);

  return retval;
}
```

locks around each call to the function `__random_r` that does the actual work.

Thus, as soon as you have more than one thread using `rand()`, you make each thread wait for the other(s) on almost every call to `rand()`. Directly using `random_r()` with your own buffers in each thread should be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Performance and threading is a black art.  The answer depends on the specifics of the compiler and libraries used to do threading, how well the kernel handles it, etc.  Basically, if your libraries for *nix are not efficient in switching, moving objects around etc, threading will in fact, be slower .   THis is one of the reasons a lot us doing thread work now work with JVM or JVM-like languages.   We can trust the runtime JVM's behavior -- it's overall speed may vary with platform, but it's consistent on that platform.  In addition, you may have some hidden wait/race conditions that you uncovered just due to timing that may not show up on Windows.

If you are in a position to change your language, consider Scala or D.  Scala is the actor driven model successor to Java, and D, the successor to C.  Both languages show their roots -- if you can write in C, D should be no problem.  Both languages however, implement the actor model.  NO MORE THREAD POOLS, NO MORE RACE CONDITIONS ETC!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, I just tried your app on Windows Vista, compiled with Borland C++, and the 2 thread version performed nearly twice as fast as the single thread.

```
pi.exe -iterations 20000000 -stats -threads 1
3.141167

Number of iterations:  20000000
Method:                Monte Carlo
Evaluation time:       12.511000 sec
Threads:               Main


pi.exe -iterations 10000000 -stats -threads 2
3.142397

Number of iterations:  20000000
Method:                Monte Carlo
Evaluation time:       6.584000 sec
Threads:               2
```

That's compiled against the thread-safe run-time library. Using the single thread library, both versions run at twice their thread-safe speed.

```
pi.exe -iterations 20000000 -stats -threads 1
3.141167

Number of iterations:  20000000
Method:                Monte Carlo
Evaluation time:       6.458000 sec
Threads:               Main


pi.exe -iterations 10000000 -stats -threads 2
3.141314

Number of iterations:  20000000
Method:                Monte Carlo
Evaluation time:       3.978000 sec
Threads:               2
```

So the 2 thread version is still twice as fast, but the 1 thread version with the single thread library is actually faster than the 2 thread version on the thread-safe library.

Looking at Borland's rand implementation, they use thread local storage for the seed in the thread-safe implementation, so it's not going to have the same negative impact on threaded code as glibc's lock, but the thread-safe implementation will obviously be slower than the single thread implementation.

The bottom line though, is that your compiler's `rand` implementation is probably the main performance issue in both cases.

**Update**

I've just tried replacing your `rand_01` calls with inline implementations of Borland's `rand` function using a local variable for the seed, and the results are consistently twice as fast in the 2 thread case.

The updated code looks like this:

```
#define MULTIPLIER      0x015a4e35L
#define INCREMENT       1

double pi_mc(int iterations) {
    unsigned seed = 1;
    long long inner = 0;
    long long outer = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
        seed = MULTIPLIER * seed + INCREMENT;
        double x = ((int)(seed >> 16) & 0x7fff) / (double) RAND_MAX;

        seed = MULTIPLIER * seed + INCREMENT;
        double y = ((int)(seed >> 16) & 0x7fff) / (double) RAND_MAX;

        double d = sqrt(pow(x, 2.0) + pow(y, 2.0));
        if (d <= 1.0) {
            inner++;
        }
        else {
            outer++;
        }
    }

    return ((double) inner / (double) iterations) * 4;
}
```

I don't know how good that is as `rand` implementations go, but it's worth at least trying on Linux to see whether it makes a difference to the performance.